# ionicLoading does not work on Android Device

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to show a loading screen on my view. On Browser the loading spinner shows up, but not on my real device (Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini, Android 4.1.2).

Is there any known error with ionicLoading and any Android versions?

```
.controller('PagesCtrl', function($rootScope,$scope, $stateParams, $http, $ionicLoading) {

  $ionicLoading.show({
    template: '<ion-spinner icon="android"></ion-spinner>'
  });


  $http({
  ....doin' some stuff here
})
  .success(function (response) { ...; $ionicLoading.hide();
  });

})
```

Comment: I have faced same issue.did you test this application using android 4.4.x versions?

Comment: can you show your log using adb logcat?

Comment: same here. in my application the $ionicLoading is sometimes working and sometimes not on android. on iOS it works fine...

Comment: I think the http request is too fast. So the Loading Spinner does not raise up. On lager record number the Loading Spinner shows up.